# Default charset in Typo3 ext_tables.sql

Tags: typo3

I use typo3 sql parser for creating tables. I want to create tables with default charset, but if I set default charset in my query:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`col1` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`col2` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`col3` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

parser returns

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
col1 varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
col2 varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
col3 text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How to set default charset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is not implemented in TYPO3 SQL Parser. But IMHO there is no need to. You should just use the DEFAULT CHARSET which is set for the DB. This should be UTF8 anyway, since TYPO3 does not support other charsets anymore (AFAIK).